# SharePoint problema with fba usng LDAP

Tags: sharepoint, ldap, fba

I configured my webapp to use FBA authentication using LDAP connection.
I used the instruction provided by this site http://davidmsterling.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/setting-up-forms-based-authentication.html

When I connect using Windows authentication it's works well, but when i try to connect using fba Sharepoint show this message sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

Any sugestion?

Tks